# How to export to csv the output of every iteration when scraping with a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, nested-lists, export-csv

I am very new to Python. I am trying to scrape a website and I have created a small code for this:

```
select = Select(character.find_element_by_id('character-template-choice'))
options = select.options
for index in range(0, len(options) - 0):
    select.select_by_index(index)
    option1 = character.find_elements_by_class_name('pc-stat-value')
    power = []
    for c in option1:
        power.append("Power:" + c.text)
    option2 = character.find_elements_by_class_name(
        'unit-stat-group-stat-label')
    skills = []
    for a in option2:
        skills.append(a.text)
    option3 = character.find_elements_by_class_name(
        'unit-stat-group-stat-value')
    values = []
    for b in option3:
        values.append(b.text)
 test = [power, skills, values]
 print(test)
 df = pd.DataFrame(test).T
 df.to_csv('test2.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

The issue I have is when I try to export "test" list of lists to csv I only get the last iteration. I want to get the data for every iteration but I don't know how to do so. Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you're subscribing your test file each `for index in range(0, len(options) - 0):` iteration. Don't you mean to write all the test after this for loop?

Comment: Thanks @ArthurPereira that was a mistake in the code I saw after I posted. I corrected it now. In this way the csv will only capture the last iteration. What I need is the csv file to capture the output of every iteration not only the last. I don't know what I need to change so that I don't overwrite the csv with every iteration

Comment: Now you are overwriting `power, skills, values` every iteration and only appending the last one to test. You have to append this three to your list each iteraton if you want to get then all.

Comment: Yes. I don't know how....Thus I am asking what i need to change :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to append these three list every iteration to get then all in the end:

```py
select = Select(character.find_element_by_id('character-template-choice'))
options = select.options
test = []  # Create empty list
for index in range(0, len(options) - 0):
    select.select_by_index(index)
    option1 = character.find_elements_by_class_name('pc-stat-value')
    power = []
    for c in option1:
        power.append("Power:" + c.text)
    option2 = character.find_elements_by_class_name(
        'unit-stat-group-stat-label')
    skills = []
    for a in option2:
        skills.append(a.text)
    option3 = character.find_elements_by_class_name(
        'unit-stat-group-stat-value')
    values = []
    for b in option3:
        values.append(b.text)
    test.append([power, skills, values])  # Add a list of lists to your test

print(test)
df = pd.DataFrame(test).T
df.to_csv('test2.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

This will give you a list `test` with `power, skills, values` inside one list for iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much. That works great. I had tried to put the test list before the loop, but I didn't know I could append like the way you showed me. As I said I am new to Python, started as a hobby 2 weeks ago. This is my first code so still a lot to learn.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, and if this or any answer solves your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.